# 'C' - How to initialise a 32 bit integer value with a 32 bit float value?

Tags: c, casting

I am trying to find a general purpose way to initialise an array or structure with parameter values.  When the parameters are consumed from the array or structure the context will be known by my function and so it will know how to use the values correctly.

To initialise the array/structure I was wanting to do something like this:

```
const void *para[] = {  // General Purpose store for parameters
    "1234",             // Store string pointer
    (void *)1234,       // Store integer value
    (void *)12.34f,     // Store float value
};
```

The string and integer parameter types are ok.  The float does not work because the compiler has no method to cast a float to a void pointer.

What I need is a way to cast a float value to its binary representation so it can treated like a 32 bit unsigned integer.  Can this be done ?

I could solve this problem with the brute force of memcpy() but this would require the 'const' to be removed.  The ultimate aim is that the code will be ported to a embedded ARM system with limited SRAM so the array/structure needs to located in ROM and so needs to be initialised by the compiler and not at run time.

Comment: You should not use `void *` as a generic value type.  Also your `memcpy` would work: your `const` applies to the pointed-to memory, not to the elements of `para`.

Comment: There is no way to have a binary representation of a floating point *literal*. Literals don't have representation, only objects (variables) do.

Comment: would a (array of) [`union`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/union) suit your needs ?

Comment: Try a compound literal (c11): Instead of `(void *)12.34f`, use a union of a `float` and `void*`.  Something like `((union { float f; void *p}){12.34f}).p`.

Answer (score 4):

Use a structure and not an array.

```
struct s_para { const char* a; int b; float c; } const para 
    = { "1234", 1234, 12.34f };
```

No need to cast anything.

Comment: This is the way to go. I would strongly suggest separating the structure definition and variable definition though.

Comment: This won't work if the combination of types varies between calls.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Sure thing. Use different structs. That's what types are *for*. You can cast their addresses to `void` if needed.

Comment: I think you missed the point.  It needed to be general purpose store of parameters, so any value could store any type.

Comment: "It needed to be general purpose store of parameters". XY problem? Why do you need a general purpose store of parameters? If you want a general purpose *pointer* to a store of parameters, you can have one, it's called `void*`. You can pass `(void*)&para` around and cast it to `s_para*` as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your generic data array contains void pointer. A pointer to a non defined data type. On many systems pointers to most datatypes do not vary in size so it does not matter what it points to. This would only become relevant when doing pointer arithmetic or accessing the content. You may know this. As you told, your code later on "knows" in what context to use which pointer. So far so good. Let's assume we have a 32bit systems as it matches your data types.

Now to your types:

- The string "1234" ist stored in the text section during compile time. And your compiler fills your data array with the pointer to that memory section.
- With the integer you explicitly cast 1234 to a void pointer, telling the compiler: "Hey, this is a pointer, not an integer". This works as long as your integer and your pointer have the same length or the pointer is bigger. So on our 32bit it's ok. So you store the value directly in the field where you would normally store a pointer to something.
- With the float the mechanism from above does not work. A float can never be interpreted as a memory address so the compiler fails.

Two options:
First, store int and float in text/constant section and just put the pointer in my array. But we have to store these values beforehand... (or maybe there's a fancy trick). This will work for any type!:

```
static int v1 = 1234;
static float v2 = 12.34f;

const void *para[] = {  // General Purpose store for parameters
    "1234",             // Store string pointer
    &v1,                // Store integer value
    &v2,                // Store float value
};
```

Second and the way i would prefere here is using a union.

```
union data_storage {
     const int t_int;
     const float t_float;
     const char *t_string;
};

const union data_storage params[] = {  // General Purpose store for parameters
    {.t_string = "1234"},           // Store string pointer
    {.t_int = 1234},                // Store integer value
    {.t_float = 12.34f},            // Store float value
};
```

I tested it with

```
fprintf(stdout, "%s\n%i\n%f\n", params[0].t_string, params[1].t_int, params[2].t_float);
```

Comment: what compiler did you test this with ? Cutting and pasting into VS2010 it does not compile.  Are there typo's ? ie '=  =' and 'data_ storage'

Comment: You are right. there are typos - narf. I used gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4. Correcting the typos now!

Comment: It seems VS2010 does not support named initialisers, ie its not C99 compliant like your gcc.  It should work on my Keil ARM though.

Comment: *pointers have the same length on the same system*.  No. Per the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf): "A pointer to `void` shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type. Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements. ...   All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. **Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements**."

Comment: Thanks. I updated the text to a more vague reply concerning pointer length. Though it did practically not happen to me... Not that I really checked ;) But this would not change anything regarding the union solution, which would be even more safe across systems in comparision to the other way.